# can't use $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get an answer from my server. Merely get the `var json.src = "http://image/path/file.jpg"` from the server but I can't even get into the `getJSON` function whatsoever.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FyMKd/)

I must be neglecting something, but I can't use `$.getJSON`, nor `$.get`
Would appreciate any help
Thanks

Comment: Read about the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: If you run your fiddle with the console/Firebug open you'll see the problem: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://hagashash.com/test1.php?a=yeah. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: #Brian Driscoll, thanks, but how and where can I see that ? I get no report like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This wont work if you're trying to load content from a different server to that on which the request is being made. This is due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Also, what's with the image `url` in your question? That's not JSON.